# Convert JS code to JSNI

Tags: javascript, jsni

im new to JS and JSNI. i am not clear about those $wnd and $doc.
for example i have this function in JS: How may i convert it JSNI ?
Trying to change document to $doc, because it stands for doc.. but it doesn't work.

```
function homeHelp(){
    var intro = introJs();
      intro.setOptions({
        steps: [
          {
            element: document.querySelector('#left_side_block'),
            intro: "This is a tooltip.",
            position:'right'
          },
          {
            element: document.querySelectorAll('#right_side_block')[0],
            intro: "Ok, wasn't that fun?",
            position: 'right'
          },
          {
            element: '#step3',
            intro: 'More features, more fun.',
            position: 'left'
          },
          {
            element: '#step4',
            intro: "Another step.",
            position: 'bottom'
          },
          {
            element: '#step5',
            intro: 'Get it, use it.'
          }
        ]
      });

      intro.start();
}
```

Comment: Have you included the proper COM package to expose the Window and Document models? You can't just straight convert javascript to JSNI for GWT.

Comment: Perhaps I'm making too many assumptions. Can you verify if this is a GWT project or not?

Comment: Yes it is GWT project. A got few simple functions like : public static native void helpJs() /*-{
  $wnd.alert();
 }-*/; which works. i just need to translate js function i posted to JSNI

Comment: i mean i want to call this function as a java method, and i cant to write it in jsni correctly